# Using ontouchmove to fire only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create some functionality to allow a user to swipe a table row to check said person in inside my database, I have had trouble using on-swipe libraries as my imports for some unknown reason are being refused by my project. I have decided to try an do something with the built in `ontouchmove` functions however whenever I use `ontouchmove` my function `checkedIn()` is fired over and over, is there any way to mix the different `ontouchmove`, `ontouchend` etc functions to only execute once per swipe?

Here is some of the code I currently have where it is implemented:

```
return (
              (session) ?
                <tr // eslint-disable-line jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions
                key={booking.id}
                onTouchMove={checkIn(booking.id)}
                >
                  <td>{booking.type}</td>
                  <td>
                    {booking.sessionId ?
                      <span>
                        {(new Date(sessions[booking.sessionId].date)).toLocaleString('en-GB', {
                          day: '2-digit',
                          month: '2-digit',
                          year: 'numeric',
                          timeZone: 'utc',
                        })} {session.name}
                      </span> :
                      <span>No session</span> // eslint-disable-line react/jsx-indent
                    }
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div>{booking.consumerName}</div>
                    <div>{booking.consumerEmail}</div>
                    <div>{booking.consumerPhonenumber}</div>
                  </td>
```

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: I have added it but it is quite a trivial question

Comment: in theory, you can implement a flag on touchmove, and remove the flag on touchend. But IMHO, swip is a very complex gesture (which direction is the user swiping, how fast is the user swiping, what if the user is sweeping instead of swiping, what if user uses multiple fingers etc). As a result, it is var better to leave that layer of abstraction to a library, IMO.

Comment: Ok I shall experiment once more with the libraries, however whenever I try to import them I get the error on build: `Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory'` all the time regardless of which library I am using.. I can ctrl + click the import and it takes me straight to the source code no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible fix for this is to simply debounce the function that is being called, you can create your own debounce function or use one from a library such as [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce).